# Можно открыть html файл как изображение, при помощи php?

Tags: php, html

Без JS и, сторонних API. Доступно только php html css.

Файл формируется на html и css, можно ли его открыть как изображения использовав php?

Comment: `Картинка формируется на html и css` - это как? поясните

Comment: @Manitikyl Опечатка. Исправил.

Comment: Вы хотите html файл перевести в картинку? я правильно понимаю вас? т.е. сделать как-бы скриншот страницы?

Comment: @Manitikyl Все верно, как-бы скриншот.

Comment: Для таких целей, нужно использовать библиотеку для создания снапшотов.

Comment: Не уверен что тупо на пхп можно такое сделать, скорей всего придется ставить какое-то расширение (либу), и потом вызывать ее с помощью пхп, но для этого еще нужны соответствующие права.

Answer (score 0):

## используя `chrome headless`

думаю, можно напрямую дёргать `chrome` через консольку

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome#screenshots

### сделать скриншот

чтобы сделать скриншот страницы используйте флаг `--screenshot`:

```
chrome --headless --disable-gpu --screenshot https://www.chromestatus.com/
```

Запуск с флагом `--screenshot` создаст файл `screenshot.png` в текущей рабочей директории.

---

пара библиотек

- https://github.com/abalozz/chrome-pdf-php (попроще)
- https://github.com/chrome-php/headless-chromium-php (для тестирования)

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать так сказать api(по сути просто перезакачка картинки) стороннего сервера и делать скриншот страницы

Я делал так

```
public function generate_image($url) {
    $rand = date('d_m_Y-H_i_s').rand(0, 100);
    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    $html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'CP1251', 'UTF-8');
    $html = iconv('CP1251', 'UTF-8', $html);
    file_put_contents('cache/html/blank-'.$rand.'.htm', $html);
    file_put_contents('cache/img/'.$rand.'.png', file_get_contents('https://mini.s-shot.ru/980x0/PNG/980/Z100/?http://b.altaym.ru/cache/html/blank-'.$rand.'.htm'));
    return array('html' => 'cache/html/blank-'.$rand.'.htm', 'img' => 'cache/img/'.$rand.'.png');
}
```

Сервис s-shot.ru

Вот документация https://www.s-shot.ru/doc/